# How do I properly update tables in a One to Many Hibernate relationship (by one request)?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate

I am using Postgresql via Hibernate, there are three tables: users, products, user_products. Here are their mappings

```
    @Entity
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @NotBlank
        private String name;
    
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Products> product;
    }



    @Entity
    public class Product{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        @NotBlank
        private String name;
    
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private Integer price;
    }
```

i know that i can get user by id, then update its field "products" and than save user back. But is it possible to do all this stuff by one request via Hibernate (or using raw sql query)?

Comment: Please define your user_products table.

Are you trying to insert new ones and update existing ones and delete missing ones?

Comment: @user I am trying to add new product for specific user.  In other words, I want to update List<Products> product for a user. Table user_products was created by hibernate for saving relationships between users and their products

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate Entity UserProduct and save it.

Is there some reason this won't work?

Comment: Do you offer remove filed List<Products> product from user entity and add field userId for entity Image? Do I got you correctly?